# How to modify default expired time of continue token in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, kubernetes-apiserver

On this page https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#retrieving-large-results-sets-in-chunks, there is a continue token that will expire after a short amount of time (by default 5 minutes).

I find that when kubernetes controller manager does cronjob syncall() function in my cluster, this token always expires and stops cronjob creating jobs on schedule.

The following is the log in kubernetes-controller-manager:

> E0826 11:26:45.441592 1 cronjob_controller.go:146] Failed to extract cronJobs list: The provided continue parameter is too old to display a consistent list result. You can start a new list without the continue parameter, or use the continue token in this response to retrieve the remainder of the results. Continuing with the provided token results in an inconsistent list - objects that were created, modified, or deleted between the time the first chunk was returned and now may show up in the list.

So I want to know can I modify the default expired time of the continue token in Kubernetes, and how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [etcd](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/896/files?short_path=0346e23#diff-0346e23dde955ef957d033a9dfa851d2) default. Any auth request to etcd will incur into that 5 seconds expiry interval. This is due to the compaction interval. The good news is that you can change that as an option in the [kube-apiserver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1436) with the `--etcd-compaction-interval` option.

Also, it looks like doing a [simple GET within the 5 minutes](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/8287#issuecomment-317566237) would actually make it extend the token timeout.

✌️

Comment: Thanks Rico.At last, we decide to reduce the count of cronjob.We think modify configuration of kube-apiserver is not a good choice for kubernetes.

Comment: Good to hear! If the answer is satisfactory can you accept it? Thanks.